# How to remove the first character from a sharepoint list item C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a line of code that basically searches a sharepoint list and if it finds a name match with a pdf, then it attaches it to that item on the sharpoint list. My issue is that I'm searching for an integer, but the column on the list that I'm searching has an 'M' before all of the integers.

So for example, I'm searching for serial number 88912, but it will never find it because on the list it is a M88912. I have attached the specific code below.

namespace SharepointAttach
{
    public static class attachumfiles
    {

```
    public static void process()
    {
        List<string> mailto = new List<string> { @"datareports@***.com" };
        string sourcepath = @"\\SERV\DocumentManagement\ASMEscans\UMscans\";
        string archivepath = @"\\SERV\DocumentManagement\ASMEscans\UMscans\archive\";
        string logfile = @"\\SERV\DocumentManagement\log.txt";

        //SharePointUtil su = new SharePointUtil();
        DebugLogNotify.notify notify = new DebugLogNotify.notify();
        DebugLogNotify.Logger logger = new DebugLogNotify.Logger(logfile);
        int firstserial;
        ListItem theListItem;
        Debug.Print(sourcepath);
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sourcepath, @"M*.pdf"))
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine(f);
            string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);
            bool result = int.TryParse(Regex.Match(fn, @"\d+", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).Value, out firstserial);
            theListItem = FindULogListItem(firstserial);
            if (theListItem == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("No matching item found in list: " + f);
                logger.Log(DateTime.Today + "ISSUE: No matching item found in list: " + f);
                notify.SendEmail(mailto, fn + " not Attached", "No matching item found in list: " + f, f);
            }
            else
            {
                string newfn = SharePointUtil.GetUniqueAttachmentName(f);
                SharePointUtil.FindAndAttachFile(theListItem, f, newfn);
                System.IO.File.Move(f, archivepath + newfn);
                logger.Log(DateTime.Today + "Attached " + f + " to list item with starting serial " + theListItem["Title"].ToString());
            }
        }

    }

    private static ListItem FindULogListItem(int serial)
    {
        bool result;
        int endserial, startserial;
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://companyweb");
        List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("UM Log");
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View></View>";
        ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(collListItem);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
        {
            result = int.TryParse(oListItem["Title"].ToString(), out startserial);
            result = int.TryParse(oListItem["Ending_x0020_Serial"].ToString(), out endserial);
            if ((serial >= startserial) && (serial <= endserial))
                return oListItem;
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're removing the M when you get the integer number out of the file.  Why not add it back?

```
var filename = "M" + result;
```

or better yet, why are you getting the number out at all?

```
var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);
```

Comment: So the main reason, is because the integers are what is used to find if the serial number falls within a range. So the column on company web could have a starting serial number of 81110 and ending serial number of 81115, and as long as my pdf file name falls within those two, then the file attaches.

I just don't think that there is a way to do that with a string variable.

Comment: Another option is if there is a way to mass update the sharepoint list to get rid of the "M" altogether on both the starting serial and ending serial columns. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Ben Am I right to assume that `int.tryparse`s in the `FindULogListItem` both fail?  If so, you would just need to remove the M before you parse.  Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: That's correct, but now that I'm looking at it, when I run the debugger and follow it line by line, it's showing a 0 for both the starting and ending serial number. Maybe I'm not calling the correct part of the sharpoint list?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding the following to the lower section of code:

```
   private static ListItem FindUMLogListItem(int serial)
    {
        bool result;
        int endserial, startserial;
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://companyweb");
        List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("UM Log");
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View></View>";
        ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(collListItem);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
        {

            result = int.TryParse(Regex.Match(oListItem["Title"].ToString(), @"\d+", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).Value, out startserial);
            result = int.TryParse(Regex.Match(oListItem["Ending_x0020_Serial"].ToString(), @"\d+", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).Value, out endserial);
            if ((serial >= startserial) && (serial <= endserial))
                return oListItem;
        }
        return null;
```

By adding the regex.match I was able to remove the "M" before converting the string to an integer. Thanks!

Comment: So basically... removing the M before you parse, like I said?